# Prevent iFrame from being busted by dropping a link

Tags: javascript, iframe, drag-and-drop, node-webkit, framebusting

I have a page that embeds an iFrame with an external domain. So I can't insert anything into its DOM. The page is run with Node-Webkit (based on Chromium), but since this behavior is the same for any browser, I consider this to be a general JavaScript problem.

I want to prevent users from "dropping links" into my page and into the iFrame.

For my page, I can embed a small JavaScript snippet that listens to the specific events, e.g. "drop" or "dragend":

```
// prevent dragging & dropping links into this application:
function handleDragEvent(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
}
var dragEvents = ['dragend',  'drop', 'dragenter', 'dragleave', 'dragover'];
for (var i = 0; i < dragEvents.length; i++) {
    window.removeEventListener(dragEvents[i], handleDragEvent);
    window.addEventListener(dragEvents[i], handleDragEvent);
}
```

So far, everything works fine: Links dropped into my page won't be navigated to. Links dragged from inside my page into the iFrame won't navigate, but still can be dragged into an external browser window (which could be prevented with "dragstart", but it's okay for me).

But if the user drops a link from an external browser directly into the iframe, it "hijacks" the whole window - not just the iframe. That's what I want to prevent.

I set up a small [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1owbdc5b/28/) that demonstrates this odd behavior (tested with Firefox and Chrome).

**Question:** How do I prevent the browser from changing the top location, if someone drops a link into the iFrame from an external window?

Comment: Did you ever found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I cant tell if you are worried about this in normal browsers or in node-webkit?

If you're asking about node-webkit (now called nwjs) then have you tried using `nwfaketop` on your iframe?

I think the info on this page may be what your after: https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Mini-browser-in-iframe

Comment: I'm worried about this in node-webkit. "nwfaketop" does not work for this issue, since it's not the site itself busting the frame (via JS detection); this seems to be the standard behaviour of the browser (node-webkit = chromium; or Firefox, Chrome, ...).

Answer (score 0):

There is a related issue for nw.js here: https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/4914

It seems the only possibility to change the drag & drop behaviour of an iframe is to add an event listener to the loaded iframe (listen for the 'load' event) and override the default behaviour, e.g. for the 'dragover' event:

```
// identify the iframe element
var frameElem = document.getElementById('main');

frameElem.contentWindow.addEventListener('dragover', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
}, false);
```